# Python Webkit making web-site screenshots using virtual framebuffer

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4, framebuffer

The problem is that I need capture web-site screenshots without running X server.

So theoretically it's possible to create a virtual frame buffer and to use it to capture screenshot.

Is there any similar solutions, any advice would be appreciated?

Sultan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use a combination of Selenium WebDriver and pyvirtualdisplay (which uses xvfb) to run your browser in a virtual display and capture screenshots.

so, the setup you need is:

- Selenium Python bindings
- pyvirtualdisplay Python package (depends on xvfb)

On Debian/Ubuntu Linux systems, you can setup everything with:

- `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip xvfb`
- `$ sudo pip install selenium`

once you have it setup, the following code example should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

this will:

- launch a virtual display
- launch Firefox browser
- navigate to google.com
- capture a screenshot
- close the browser
- stop the virtual display

Comment: @Corey-Goldberg  how do we reduce the image quality? the images are very high quality and heavy

Comment: Max, I don't think it is configurable (afaik), but you could easily run images through a post-processing program to do that.

Comment: Hi Corey, I am not using xvfb binaries , but need to controll the screenshot size . Can i do it in Selenium. I.e screen shots should be very small in size

Comment: Any non firefox based solution?

Comment: selenium webdriver supports all major browsers.