# Trying to gran a screenshot of a tube website takes forever

Tags: python, selenium, webpage-screenshot

using the code in [Python Webkit making web-site screenshots using virtual framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572575/python-webkit-making-web-site-screenshots-using-virtual-framebuffer)
 as it is to take a screenshot of a random tube video and it just takes on forever plus it just eats up all my memory any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try other drivers such as HtmlUnitDriver or ChromeDriver, if you do need Firefox try different versions, the firefox 8 alpha/beta takes half the ram. If you are not,  try to maintain your seleminum session for multiple uses and websites as the `display.start() browser = webdrive()` to `browswer.quit()` overhead is quite high and slows things down.  Also you can try using the [vncserver method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux/143148#143148) or [Python and QtWebKit as this describes](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/)